# Studying SQL injections: can't drop tables

Tags: django, postgresql, security, web

The code below is about Python + Django + PostgreSQL.
But maybe the question is limited to psycopg2 behaviour.

I'm studying web security and namely SQL injections. Learning purpose only.

This is World sample database (http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000150&release_id=366#world-world-1.0-title-content).

I have invented these SQL injections:

```
1'; drop table city cascade;select 1 where 'me'='me
1'; drop owned by admin;select 1 where 'me'='me
```

I'm in the debug mode, so I can see errors if any.
Well, these injections don't produce any errors.

But the tables are still present.

And I can execute those commands in psql:

```
world=# drop owned by admin;
DROP OWNED
world=# \dt
No relations found.
```

**QUESTION: Could you help me understand why my SQL injections don't produce the same result?**

**world=# \dt**

```
            List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  | Owner 
--------+-----------------+-------+-------
 public | city            | table | admin
 public | country         | table | admin
 public | countrylanguage | table | admin
```

**world=# \d+ city**

```
                          Table "public.city"
   Column    |     Type     | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer      | not null  | plain    |              | 
 name        | text         | not null  | extended |              | 
 countrycode | character(3) | not null  | extended |              | 
 district    | text         | not null  | extended |              | 
 population  | integer      | not null  | plain    |              |
```

**views.py**

```
class FormView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request,
                      "home/city.html")

    def post(self, request):
        city = request.POST.get("city")
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='world', user='admin', password='password')
        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            print("Unable to connect to db!")
            exit();
        cur = conn.cursor()
        select = "select countrycode, district from city where name='{}'".format(city)
        cur.execute(select);

        selection = cur.fetchall()

        return render(request,
                      "home/city.html",
                      context={'city': city, 'selection': selection})
```

**city.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>City</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="city">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<h2>Country code and district for {{ city }}:</h2>
<ul>
    {% for row in selection %}
        <li>{{ row.0 }} {{ row.1 }}</li>
    {% empty %}
        <p>Nothing so far.</p>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Turn on `log_statements = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and look at the SQL statements in the database log. That should help you figure out what arrives at the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conn.commit() was absent.

Reference http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html

So, in case of just selection drop tables seems to be hardly possible.

But if we execute something like "insert into city ...", then we have to use conn.commit() and here we can drop tables via an SQL injection.